# How to limit date time picker to a certain date

Tags: c#, date, datetimepicker

I have two date time pickers to set it from date to date

```
   string DF = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-M-d");  
   string DT = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-M-d");
```

how can I limit date time picker.

I want use it to limit `dateTimePicker2` date to allow user make it not less then `dateTimePicker1` value. For example if `DF` is `1980/8/1` then `dateTimePicker2` value `DT` range must be limited until this point depending on the `dateTimePicker1` value, in this case from `1980/8/1` and higher in ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [`MinDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate(v=vs.110).aspx) to the first `dateTimePicker1` value like:

```
dateTimePicker2.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

Place that code in the `ValueChanged` event of `DateTimePicker` like:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker2.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
}
```

Also make sure that the event is properly attached.

```
this.dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged);
```

Answer (score 2):

Working Code

```js
 
var  setSecondDateMinValue =  function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("date2");
    input.setAttribute("min", this.value);
}
   document.getElementById("date1").onchange = setSecondDateMinValue;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date"  id="date1" />
<input type="date"  id="date2" />
```